# Compare values in a list to a data frame and if true, amend value to item in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
trade_count = 3
Buyer = ["Company", "Company", "Company"]
'''
MAPPING = pd.read_excel(r"H:\Metals_tempest\MAPPING.xlsx", na_filter = False)
print(Buyer)

# Buyer = pd.DataFrame({'col':Buyer})
# print (df)

for i in range (0, trade_count):
    # Buyer[i] = MAPPING['Tempest'].where(MAPPING['Ticket'] == Buyer[i])
    # Buyer.loc[Buyer[i]==MAPPING[i],Buyer[i]] = MAPPING['Tempest']
    # Buyer[i] = MAPPING['Tempest'] = MAPPING.isin(Buyer).any()

print(Buyer)
'''
```

[Here is a screenshot of my mapping table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCfBK.png)

I want to be able to read my Ticket column in my mapping table, see if Buyer[i] exists in the mapping table and if it does remap the value to the Tempest column value from my mapping table

[EG when mum == mum and dad == dad, new variable = child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29OJI.png)

Comment: Loops are frowned on in pandas. In this case, I think you'll probably get further using `np.where`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `MAPPING` to a dictionary and use it in a list comprehension:

```
map_dict = MAPPING.set_index("Ticket")["Tempest"].to_dict()
Buyer = [map_dict.get(i, i) for i in Buyer]
```

Comment: how you would deal with if you need two comparisons to be true for a new value

Comment: This should work for whatever you have in MAPPING and Buyer. I'm not sure what you mean by "new value"

Comment: See the new photo I added to the original post, tks

Comment: Still doesn't clear any confusion. Buyer has only 1-dimensional values. Where are you comparing the second value from? Please see [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how to ask.

Comment: Okay imagine we have a location value and a terms value, eg if location = London and terms = truck, x (new variable) = LndTruck. How do I do this so that it takes it from the mapping on my excel sheet?

Comment: You can have a dictionary with tuples as keys. The concept remains the same. I'd suggest posting a new question if you want specific help with that.